# how to encode image to base64 in python and insert to HTML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64

the program I'm making sends emails to our customers and the API I'm working with allows me to write in HTML and insert variables, I'm trying to make one of those variables an image. Basically what I'm doing is opening an image in python, encoding it to base 64 and then concatenating it to a variable with the HTML IMG tag. When I execute my code I get

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

I'm using Python 3.6
This is my code:

```
with open("TA203_2.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:
    equipment_image = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    logger.debug(str(equipment_image))
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to convert it to a string.